# render function is called many times in React+Backbone todomvc example

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs, render

Visit the todomvc source code, line 150:
[TodoMVC Backbone+React Example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react-backbone/js/app.jsx)

I add "console.log(todo)" like this:

```
            var todoItems = shownTodos.map(function (todo) {
            console.log(todo)
            return (
```

If todos have 3 items, the console.log would be called 3*3=9 times.
100 items would be called 100*100 = 10000 times.
I think it's a performance problem.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it a performance problem? What causes the unnecessary renders?

Comment: This question is most likely going to be closed because your assumption is wrong and it's not really answerable. If you put console.log inside a loop inside your render function it's normal that it will log multiple times (once for each item in the loop). This doesn't mean that TodoApp.render is executed multiple times.